# Editing artist tag for an mp3 file based on filename

Tags: id3

I have files of the form "Song Artist - Song Title". For instance

Bastille - Pompeii (Kat Krazy Remix)

Iggy Azalea ft. Rita Ora - Black Widow

Sia - Chandelier

and I would like to edit their id3 tags so that the artist name is the string that comes before space dash space. So for the song "Sia - Chandelier" the artist would be "Sia". Is there a simple way to do this with a script? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) for such tasks.

In Mp3tag you will find the (id3tag) converter 'filename - tag'.
 If the filename appears in the form "Song Artist - Song Title", you can use the converter 'filename - tag' (ALT-2) with the formatstring "%artist% - %title%".

All the possible formatstrings are visible with a click on the little black arrow on the right side of the format string input box.
The preview has to show a valid result, otherwise the preview- and OK-button remains disabled.